# Proof X has finite expectation and |E(X)−E(Y)|<M

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables such that
$P (|X − Y | < M ) = 1$
for some constant $M$ . Show that if $Y$ has finite expectation, then $X$ has finite expectation and
$|E(X) − E(Y) | < M$ .

Comment: Can you please write down the definitions of $E[X]$ and $E [Y]$?

Comment: $E(X)$ is the expectation.

Comment: Of course. I am asking for the formula, by definition, of the expectation. Now, I want you to write down $E(X)- E(Y)$ and stare at the expression. That's all.

Comment: I want to ask can we write relation between $E(|X-Y|)$ and $ |E(X)-E(Y)|$. Because it is clear that $E(|X-Y|)$ is less than M.

Comment: Yes, you can write a relation. That is the triangle inequality in a different version. The answer below is helpful.

Comment: ok, Got it. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73318/discussion-between-pta-cdv-and----).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $P(|X - Y| < M) = 1$ we can write

$$E[|X - Y|] = \int_{\Omega} |X - Y| dP = \int_{\{|X - Y| < M\}} |X - Y| dP + \int_{\{|X - Y| \geq M\}} |X - Y| dP$$

Since $P(|X - Y| < M) = 1$ we can say $\int_{\{|X - Y| \geq M\}} |X - Y| dP = 0$, and $\int_{\{|X - Y| < M\}} |X - Y| dP = \int_\Omega |X - Y| \mathbb{1}_{\{|X - Y| < M\}} dP < M P(|X - Y| < M) = M$.

In short, $E[|X - Y|] < M$.

Now using the fact that $E[|Y|] = C < \infty$, use the triangle inequality to get

$$E[|X|] = E[|X - Y + Y|] \leq E[|X - Y|] + E[|Y|] < M + C < \infty$$

Using the usual integral inequality we then get

$$|E[X] - E[Y]| = |E[X - Y]| = \left|\int_\Omega (X - Y) dP\right| \leq \int_\Omega |X - Y| dP = E[|X - Y|] < M$$